# How to extract data from database in Home page wordpress with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, database, wordpress

I want to call `/home/***/public_html/subdomains/busuioc/wp-content/themes/scalia/json_gallery_data.php`
the content of `json_gallery_data.php` is:

```
global $wpdb;
$programs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM program_tv");
$tv=array();
foreach ( $programs as $program){
    $tv[]=$program->day;
}
echo json_encode($tv);
```

the ajax file is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
     loadData();
});
var loadData=function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: 'site.com/wp-content/themes/scalia/json_gallery_data.php'
    }).done(function(data){
        var videos=JSON.parse(data);
        for(var i in videos){
           alert(videos[i]);
        }
    });
```

};

Comment: Change the AJAX type to GET!

Comment: `console.log(data)` to see if it needs `JSON.parse`?

Comment: GET site.com/wp-content/themes/scalia/json_gallery_data.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I don't know what to do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$wpdb` won't be defined since you're bypassing wordpress, you'll have to use wordpress' ajax api to have access to it.

put your code block inside a function, and place it in the `functions.php` file of your theme (if you want to keep it in a separate file, include it in the `functions.php` file)

```
function my_ajax_handler(){
    global $wpdb;
    $programs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM program_tv");
    $tv=array();
    foreach ( $programs as $program) 
    {
        $tv[]=$program->day;
    }
    echo json_encode($tv);
    wp_die();
}
```

after that you have to "register" it with wordpress' ajax api, and you do it like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_call_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_call_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );
```

[wp ajax (action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29)

[wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_%28action%29)

now, the file you're going to call in your ajax request is `site.tld/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. you can hardcode it, but that wouldn't be the best thing to do. ideally you should store it in a javascript variable, and wordpress has a handy function to do exactly that. put the below in the callback function that you're using to [enqueue your scripts/styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/script.js', array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

[wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

now all you have to do is to modify your ajax call to include the ajax trigger we registered before,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data: { 'action': 'call_my_ajax_handler' }
})
```

notice how `call_my_ajax_handler` is the same thing we "registered" before.

assuming that there aren't any errors, you should see the expected result.

- none of the code has been tested.

take a look at the [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) codex entry as well.

Comment: sure thing :)
take a look at [check_ajax_referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) as well, especially if you plan on doing admin side stuff.